# Using jquery, Need to hide a div and animate the width of another div at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a page with a google map embed and legend to the right. When a "hide legend" button is clicked, I would like to hide the legend div and grow the width of the map div from 720 pixels to fill the page width (1000px).

I'm also then hiding the "hide legend" button and showing a "show legend" button.

It basically works but the map div flashes and doesn't animate smoothly. It starts as 720 pixels; the legend slides over nice and smooth, and then the mp div appears filling the page at 1000 pixels.

This is driving me crazy...and I have searched and can't find my exact circumstances. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Here's my jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".hideLegend").click(function () {
   $(this).hide(); 
   $("#legend").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
   $("#map").animate({ width: "1000"}, 500); 
   $(".showLegend").show(); 


});

  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the elements are placed relative, and as `hide()` removes the elements from the documents flow by setting the `display` to none, things start moving around ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hide` and `animate` take a function to be executed on animation completion. Use that to start the next animation, then after that's finished, perform the `show`. Something like:

```
$("#legend").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500, function () {
    $("#map").animate({ width: "1000"}, 500, function () {
        $(".showLegend").show();
    });
});
```

**EDIT: From comments, combined with your Fiddle, this produces the desired results**:

```
$(".hideLegend").click(function () {
    $(this).hide(); 
    $("#legend").animate({ width: "0"}, 500);
    $("#map").animate({ width: "1000"}, 500, function () {
       $(".showLegend").show();
       $("#tabs").hide();
    });
});

$(".showLegend").click(function () {
    $(this).hide(); 
    $("#tabs").show();
    $("#legend").animate({ width: "280" }, 500);
    $("#map").animate({ width: "720"}, 500, function () {
        $(".hideLegend").show();
    });
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mpdc/3/**

Comment: That helps but I want it to happen at the same time so that the legend moves over while the map is filling the page width. I had that earlier but it makes it so that the animations happen one after the other instead of simultaneously.

Comment: @user2217431 Is that not possible by using your existing code but wrapping the `.showlegend` show inside the callback function of the map animate? Can you post a jsfiddle with your markup?

Comment: First time using jfiddle; hope I did it properly:  http://jsfiddle.net/ltdesign/2Mpdc/

Comment: @user2217431 I've fixed it for you, you don't need `<script>` tags in the JavaScript part and when using jQuery you need to select it from the dropdown on the left. Here's your fixed one: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mpdc/1/

Comment: @user2217431 How do I invoke the animations on your Fiddle?

Comment: I did change my jfiddle thing so it had the jquery invoked...sorry. And thanks for the new fixed on mattytommo...Now you can see my quandary. The map div gets wider after the legend has been hidden. I'd like it to animate all at once.

Comment: @user2217431 Try this http://jsfiddle.net/2Mpdc/2/ I changed them both to use `animate`, that way they can happen at the same time. The only thing you need to do is hide your tabs when it slides.

Comment: Oh, click the hide legend box to see animation.

Comment: Hmmm, well I'd like to see the content sldie over as well; not disappear and then slide. Instead of width: 0 perhaps left: -280 ...or something to pull it off the page?

Comment: @user2217431 Hmmm then you'd end up with nasty scrollbars, unless you hacked away at it. Is that what you want?

Comment: No, I thought this would be fairly easy to achieve. I see this a lot. Maybe I am using the wrong effect? Here's an example of what I am trying to do: roadtrippers.com   See how their tool bar can be easily shown and hidden?

Comment: I think this works well; I decided to hide everything before it slides away and I think it will work out fine. Thank you for your help, mattytommo!!